# Executable name (AppName1.exe) and the app name (AppName2.app) are different

Tags: xamarin.ios

I get the following warning in MonoTouch. How can I solve it? I want both to be named App1 but I can not find the right spot.

Thanks!

```
warning MT0030: The executable name (App1.exe) and the app name (App2.app) are different, this may prevent crash logs from getting symbolicated properly.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The app name (App2.app) is taken from the name of the project. You can right-click the project and 'Rename' to change it.

The executable name (App1.exe) can be changed in the project's options (right-click -> Options -> Build/Output -> Assembly Name).

Comment: Why isn't the app name based on options->iOS Application -> Application Name?

Comment: @PaulBatum: I don't know (this decision was take before my time), but I can't see it matter much (after all it's not user-visible, unless you start poking around in iTunes).

Comment: Well if I want to have a project name that is foo-ios, I get the MT0030 warning because it won't let me set the assemblyname to foo-ios (it says it must be alphanumeric).

Comment: Strange decision of MT team... I have either to change my build system and rename project (projects are generated and are not commited to VCS, and it is more convinient to name them in non-user-friendly way), or to show users something like PROJIOSIOS to avoid warning. BTW, does it really affect crash logs in Monotouch ?

Comment: Yes, I've personally seen it happen.

Comment: It seems ok to name your app Foo.iOS but call your output assembly name FooiOS (without the period). I don't see compiler warnings by following that convention.

Comment: On VS 2013, the assembly name are in the "Application" config.

Answer (score 3):

Open the project options in Xamarin Studio and navigate to the "Build" section. Verify that *Assembly Name* in the **Output** Tab matches *Application Name* in the **iOS Application** Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump this old question, but I found the following two entries in the Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>AppName</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>AppNameX</string>
```

The **CFBundleExecutable** is where I had to fix my app name. I'm not sure, but it seems VS/XS settings do not change this entry in the file regardless.

Hope this helps ;)