# Executable name and the app name are different

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725785/executable-name-appname1-exe-and-the-app-name-appname2-app-are-different) discussion, except my error is:

`warning : The executable name (MyAppiOS.app) and the app name (MyAppiOS.app) are different, this may prevent crash logs from getting symbolicated properly.`

As you can see, they actually are the same but I'm still getting the warning. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: That's strange as the executable name should end with `.exe`, not `.app`. Can you add a link to a full (re)build of your solution ?

Comment: Here's a link to the MSBuild output: http://pastebin.com/mJrShcLy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just ended up working by itself at some stage, after uprgading Xamarin.